# Insert rows between datasets

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, dataset

With reference to question [Modify rows added into dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908124/modify-rows-added-into-dataset/6908308#6908308), what should i do if i need to include the Dataset 2 rows somewhere between dataset 1 rows?

Say for example;

Dataset 1

Row 1 
Row 2 
Row 3 
Row 4

DataSet 2

Row A 
Row B 
Row C

hence, this should be like

Row 1 
Row A 
Row 2 
Row 3 
Row B 
Row 4 
Row C

Comment: Rows in a Table are unordered. Try to think of  a solution based on Sorting (in a DataView)

Comment: if im completely honest; this issue could be resolved by improving your database query.

Comment: there is no such query. I am using data-table-row-column.

Comment: What is the criteria to use for determining where to insert row x from table 2 into table 1?  The answers below are correct, all that needs to be added is logic for determining *where* to insert the row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use InsertAt methos

```
var row = dataSet2.Tables[0].NewRow();
// Copy rowA to row
dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, position);
```

Comment: i tried that. It throw an error mentioning that "This row already belongs to another table"

Comment: @Xor power: You should create new Row instance, and then add it by InsertAt

Comment: Plus, the position is not fixed as to where i would be inserting dataset 2 rows., It is purely based on dataset 1 conditions

Comment: can i get the row position from the dataset 1?

Comment: I am not able to find the index of the dataset-1 rows. This is needed so as to i could find where to insert the rows of dataset2. Similar to position in InsertAt argument

Comment: @Xor - The position (index) of the insertion in dataset1 would be based on whatever criteria you're using to determine where to insert the rows.  I.e., if row 3 in dataset1.Tables[0] is where you want to insert the next row from dataset2.Tables[0], you'd use index 3 (to insert it after the row) or index 2 (to insert it before the row).  It would really help to know what logic you're using to determine when to insert one of the dataset2.Table[0] rows.

Comment: thanks Tim. There is one logic as to when the column A is "Y", then i need to insert the row. Plus i would also need to know what the row number or the position is, so that i could use InsertAt command

Comment: @Xor - Column A in dataset1.Tables[0], column A in dataset2.Tables[0], or both?

Comment: columnA in dataset1.tables[0]

Answer (score 1):

First of all datatable has rows and dataset holds datatables.
To insert row to specific index you can use InsertAt method.

```
myDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(myNewRow, indexToInsertTo);
```

Comment: What was the difference between your answer and the one given before ? please dont repeat same answers.

Comment: @Karan the difference is TIME, when I posted my answer I saw that Peyman also posted it - I was too slow thats it. Just wanted to check (by starting VS) if I'am correct about that method before clicking "Post your Answer".

Comment: ok i thought you just copied it same answer so its of no use thats y i just voted it down sorry for misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on the comments in the answer by Peyman, here is a brute force method, based on the following assumption:

If a given row in table 1 has "Y" in column "A", insert a row from table 2 after the current row in table 1.  Take the next unused row from table 2 every time this condition is met.

I will say up front that this is ugly, and prone to a lot of problems, and there's probably a better way to do it (LINQ?), and perhaps an explanation of what Xor is trying to accomplish (i.e., the concept/rules/logic behind it) might lead to better or alternative solutions.

Here goes:

```
int tbl1Index = 0;
int tbl1Rows = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
int tbl2Index = 0;
int tbl2Rows = dataset2.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

DataRow row;

// Do this loop until either tbl1 has been gone through completely or table 2 has been gone 
// through completely, whichever comes first.
while (tbl1Index < tbl1Rows && tbl2Index < tbl2Rows)
{
    if (dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[tbl1Index]["A"].ToString() == "Y")
    {
        // Copy the next available row from table 2
        row = dataset2.Tables[0].Rows[tbl2Index];
        // Insert this row after the current row in table 1
        dataset1.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(row, tbl1Index + 1);

        // Increment the tbl1Index.  We increment it here because we added a row, even 
        // though we'll increment tbl1Index again before the next iteration of the while loop
        tbl1Index++;
        // Since we just inserted a row, we need to increase the count of rows in table 1 to
        // avoid premature exit of the while loop
        tbl1Rows++;
        // Increment tbl2Index so the next time a match occurs, the next row will be grabbed.
        tbl2Index++;
    }

    // Increment tbl1Index.  If there was a match above, we'll still need to increment to
    // account for the new row.  
    tbl1Index++;
}
```

Wow...that's really, really, really ugly....